# JS: Run script with different var's at different places

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display the elapsed time since a timestamp in a sentence. From each data point (I have 16 in total) I get the (Unix?) time. Access to the timestamp with "var newStamp".

```
var name = "time_room";
var startStamp = {Timestamp};


var newDate = new Date();
var newStamp = newDate.getTime();
var timer;
function updateClock() {
    newDate = new Date();
    newStamp = newDate.getTime();
    var diff = Math.round((newStamp-startStamp)/1000);
    var d = Math.floor(diff/(24*60*60));
        diff = diff-(d*24*60*60);
    var h = Math.floor(diff/(60*60));
        diff = diff-(h*60*60);
    var m = Math.floor(diff/(60));
        diff = diff-(m*60);
    var s = diff;
    if (d == 0 && h == 0 && m == 0) { 
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML =s+" sec ago.";}
    else if (d == 0 && h == 0) { 
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML =m+" min and "+s+" sec ago.";}
    else if (d == 0) { 
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML =h+" hours and "+m+" min ago.";}
    else if (d != 0) { 
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML =d+" days and "+h+" hours ago.";}
    }
    setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

In HTML, I then display the data point like this:

```
<td>Last presence:</td>
    <td><p class="tinytime" id="TIMESTAMP"></p>
</td>
```

But what can I do if I have 16 timestamps and want to display them in 16 different places?
Like this...

```
Page one:
<td>Last presence:</td>
   <td><p class="tinytime" id="TIMESTAMP"></p>
</td>
Page two:
<td>Timestamp 2...</td>
   <td><p class="tinytime" id="TIMESTAMP2"></p>
</td>
<td>Timestamp 3...</td>
   <td><p class="tinytime" id="TIMESTAMP3"></p>
</td>
and so on...
```

Including 16x times the same script with different var's isnt a good way, right?

Comment: hint: use `let` or `const` instead of `var` and for your use case can be good `Objects`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: 16 html dom element is static or this is dynamically inserted too?